# CSS Grid Repeat not working in Safari on Mobile

Tags: css, grid, html-framework-7

As far as I know, CSS Grid is supported by Safari as of last month.  Yet, when I load a page with a grid container, my items aren't dynamically repeated -- they take up the whole container width.

```
 .selection-container {
     margin: 50px;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
     background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.6);
     border-style: inset;
     border-width: 2px;
     border-color: red;

 }
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="categories-container"  v-show="selectedCategory==''" class="selection-container">      
<div v-for="(val, key) in categories" :key=key @click="selectedCategory=key">
    <f7-card :title="key" role="button" class="category"></f7-card>
</div>      
</div>
```

Is there some step I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Even if Safari supports CSS Grid Layout since 10.1:

> Safari does not yet support intrinsic and extrinsic sizing with grid
>   properties such as grid-template-rows" (or grid-template-columns)

(source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Comment: What does that sentence mean? Does it mean Safari doesn't support the properties `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns`? Does it mean that certain values, or perhaps certain units, are not supported on those properties? Or does it mean that a specific behavior, achievable through the use of those properties, is not yet implemented?